# displaying all lines in list box from a file in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I have this code which is suppose to display all lines which contains a specifies string but instead of returning all lines with that string it only returns last line which contains the string. How can I make it to display all lines?

```
if(bookingType == "Express")
        {
            string stringToSearch = @"Express";
            string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"pathway");
            foreach (string line in lines)
            {
                if (line.Contains(stringToSearch))
                {
                    lstAvailableTrains.Items.Clear();
                    lstAvailableTrains.Items.Add(line);
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are clearing the items in each time.You need to move clear out of the loop

```
lstAvailableTrains.Items.Clear();
foreach (string line in lines)
{
  if (line.Contains(stringToSearch))
  {     
     lstAvailableTrains.Items.Add(line);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use LINQ, and set the ListBox's `ItemsSource` property:

```
using System.Linq;
...

lstAvailableTrains.ItemsSource =
    File.ReadAllLines("pathway").Where(line => line.Contains(stringToSearch));
```